# Get id value from ModelChoiceField that passes to model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

*form.py*

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      parent_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required = False)
      name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)

      class Meta:
         model = Category
         fields = ('parent_id', 'name')
```

*models.py*

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view.py

```
class CreateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'create.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = CreateForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})
```

A form is created in template in *create.html*
[image: html page]

My problem is when I choose category from dropdown list by ModelChoiceField for parent_id in create.html, I get the object, not the Id. That's why it displays error "[field name] must be an integer" and can't pass the value to the database as the parent_id is declared Integer at models.py. I need to get the id of selected value and pass it to the database under 'parent_id' field.
I know something that is working in view:

```
# parent_id = form.cleaned_data('parent_id').id
```

I got the id by this way but it didn't help me because of form.save() won't take anything from view. it works directly with *form.py* and just save it here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you did not do it with a `ForeignKey`, Django would generate the parent_id for you. Anyway, `self.request.POST('parent_id')` contains your `id`

Comment: @Lemayzeur , yes, I got the point, but can't solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, just use a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (A many-to-one relationship) instead of saving the id directly yourself with *parent_id*. Django will do everything for you.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()
    parent = models.ForeinKey("self",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) 
    # name it parent
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Your form would become:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required = False)
      name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Then you're good to go, you save the form and create an instance with as parent a `Category` instance itself.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: Would you please me why parent_id is replaced by parent

Comment: with a `foreignkey` Django will automatically generate the id for you, a concatenation with `field_name+'_id'`. And also parent will contain the instance, not the id, it's more obvious to name it `parent` rather than `parent_id`..  for instance `category.parent_id.id` would not make sense. but with parent as field name, `category.parent.id` makes more sense since `category.parent` is an instance not an id

Comment: Thanks. I understood this. I have a question. As required = false in ModelChoiceField, if I want to set 0 for 'parent' when the field isn't selected, is there any way to do that?

Comment: The ModelChoiceField will generate an `empty_label` in template, there will not be any problems when chose nothing since the model field expects this with `blank=True,null=True`

Comment: but it shows an error that "NOT NULL constraint failed: catagory_category.parent_id". Please give me some hints to solve it

Comment: after the change, did you run `makemigrations` & `migrate`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172789/discussion-between-rafee-muhammad-and-lemayzeur).

Answer (score 1):

You can rename `parent_id` form's field to just `parent`. So `form.save()` will expect parent instance:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required = False)
      name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)

      class Meta:
         model = Category
         fields = ('parent', 'name')
```

Note, `parent` should be model's `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Good point, but take a look at his model, `parent_id` is not `ForeignKey`, just an `IntegerField()`

Comment: @Lemayzeur oops, didnt see it. Thanks.